# Get data from datatable into a string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I use a SQL query and store the result into a datatable and now I want to write a specific cell data in to a string or char.

Below is the code I want to get the data from `row[0]` `column[1]`

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SeatsDetails WHERE ServiceNo='"+srno+"' AND Date='"+date+"'", con);
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
String t1 = (String) dt.Rows[0][1];
```

Comment: Umm....the code you wrote should do the trick, unless there's something you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @Tim: Unless there are no results from the SQL query.

Comment: @Neil - true.  I rather assumed a null check would be performed in the full code (yes, I know...assuming is a silly thing to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had got it using, Thanks fo the effort.

```
String t1 = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LinQ queries in c# is also a good option to fetch all the results:

```
List<string> DataList2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("value")).ToList();
```