# Get values from data table and pass it to label

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I want to get the `FullName` when the user login succesfully and put their `FullName` to the `label`

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SystemDatabase"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
sqlconn.Open();
string query = "Select * from UserAccount where Username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and Password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query,sqlconn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count == 1) 
{
    FrmPOS frm = new FrmPOS();
    frm.Show();
    frm.lblCashierName.Text = ?//here i want to display the fullname from the UserAccount table.
    this.Hide();
}
```

I don't know how to get the data from the `DataTable`. Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: DataTable consists of multiple rows, you need to select single [DataRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=net-5.0) and mention column name in Square bracket to get the text you wanted. Note: *You should mention correct given column name of sql in DataRow* see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119993/datarow-select-cell-value-by-a-given-column-name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from datatable into a string in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640441/get-data-from-datatable-into-a-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString()` to get the FullName column from first record.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection (conn))
{
    sqlconn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM UseAccount WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn)
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text.Trim());
    
        using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt != null || dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                FrmPOS frm = new FrmPOS();
                frm.Show();
                frm.lblCashierName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, I would like to enhance your source code for some best practices

1. Apply using block to SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataAdapter. Thus when each process ends, the using block will perform `Dispose` to release resources.
2. Apply SqlCommand with Parameters (a.k.a Parameterized query) as your way could lead to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) by concatenating the value into command.
3. Checking DataTable to ensure it has record(s) then only proceed; aims to solve possible NullReferenceException happened when no data return.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SystemDatabase"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
sqlconn.Open();
string query = "Select * from UserAccount where Username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and Password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,sqlconn);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read() == true) 
{
    FrmPOS frm = new FrmPOS();
    frm.Show();
    frm.lblCashierName.Text = reader["FullName"].ToString();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: You are welcome @SimSim, but I forgot to change the variable name for SqlCommand, it should be `command`, lol :)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Yep, I agree with @marc_s suggestions

Comment: @marc_s yes sir, i will make a `stored procedure`  out of it